# Realizar peticion a un webservice hecho C# por medio de PHP

Tags: php, c#, xml, webservice, curl

Es la primera vez que tengo que utilizar un webservice y me estoy dando de topes. Tengo una aplicación hecha en PHP, en la que necesito obtener una lista de proveedores de servicios turísticos con sus respectivas tarifas.

El dueño del web service me ha mandado el ejemplo de como hacer la petición a su servidor, pero me lo ha dado en C#, le pedí un ejemplo para PHP pero es un poco cerrado. Me dice que solo debo hacer la petición por POST y XML con los datos me ha proporcionado.

Alguien puede ayudarme a convertir este código a su equivalente con PHP o decirme en donde me estoy equivocando, ya que ejecuto el código y el webservice me devuelve el error...

**Empty reply from serverRespuesta :**

He de comentar que he intentado hacer el código equivalente de C# pero en PHP por medio de CURL, he visto ejemplos y he logrado hacer unas cosas, pero sin llegar al objetivo final.

Pongo el ejemplo en C# que me pasaron. y el código en PHP que he podido hacer.

**De antemano GRACIAS**

```
//CODIGO EN C#


publicstaticRServicesGMGetServices(intsiteId, intsId){
   //Se ingresan los datos que se mandaran en REST justo con autenticacion
   HttpWebRequestrequest = null;
   request = WebRequest.Create("http://api.tuulbax.com/service.svc/getServicesGM") asHttpWebRequest;
   request.Method = "POST";
   request.ContentType = "application/xml";
   request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("user:password")));
   StreampostStream = request.GetRequestStream();

   //se crea un objeto de la clase GServicesGM y se mete el siteId y sId
   GServicesGM r = newGServicesGM();
   r.siteId = siteId;
   r.sId = sId;

   //se convierten los datos a xml con clase ToXElement
   varprov = ToXElement<GServicesGM>(r);

   //Se manda valores REST en postStream y el cuerpo en prov
   using (varstreamWriter = newStreamWriter(postStream)){
       streamWriter.Write(prov);
       streamWriter.Flush();
       }

       //Se recibe la respuesta de API en formato xml
       HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() asHttpWebResponse;
       Streamvar = response.GetResponseStream();
       var resultado = "";

       //se mete respuesta en variable resultado
       using (varstreamReader = newStreamReader(var)){
           resultado = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
           }

           //se convierte resultado a xml y se mete a dato XElement
           XElementxmlTree = XElement.Parse(resultado);
           RServicesGMserv = newRServicesGM();
           varserializer = newXmlSerializer(typeof(RServicesGM));

           //Se le quita el tipo xml y se ingresan a clases y listas correspondientes
           serv = (RServicesGM)serializer.Deserialize(xmlTree.CreateReader());

           // se retorna el objeto de la lista con todos los servicios y detalles
           returnserv;
           }

           //clase que convierte objeto a ToXElement
           publicstaticXElementToXElement<T>(thisobjectobj){
               using (varmemoryStream = newMemoryStream()){
                   using (TextWriterstreamWriter = newStreamWriter(memoryStream)){
                            varxmlSerializer = newXmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                            xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter, obj);
                            return XElement.Parse(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray()));
                            }
                       }
                }
```

```
//CODIGO EN PHP

//Funcion que convierte a ASCII y code64 el usuario y contraseña

function toASCII($cadena){

        $cadena = stripslashes($cadena);
        $ascii = "";
        for($i = 0; $i < strlen($cadena); $i++){
                $ascii.= ord(substr($cadena,$i));
                $ascii.= ",";
        }       
        $ascii = substr($ascii, 0, -1);
        $encoding_ASCII = explode(',', $ascii);
        $encoding_ASCII = array_map("chr",$encoding_ASCII);
        $result_ASCII = implode('',$encoding_ASCII);
        $codificacion = base64_encode($result_ASCII);

        return $codificacion;
}

$UserPass = "usuario:password";
$params = array("siteId" => 3, "sId" => 0);
$ch = curl_init('http://api.tuulbax.com/service.svc/getServicesGM');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/xml','Content-length: 2500'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, toASCII($UserPass));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);


$response = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo "ERROR : ".curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);

echo "Respuesta : ".$response;
```

Answer (score 1):

Bueno después de mucho buscar y probar he encontrado la solución, y la dejare aquí por si a alguien le sirve en un futuro, y es que me di cuenta que muchos webservices están hechos en C# y poco se documenta para su uso con PHP.

Bueno iré explicando un poco tomando como ejemplo el anterior código para mostrar las fallas que tenia...

Utilice CURL PHP para hacer la petición al webservice hecho en C#.

Primeramente no era necesario convertir a ASCII ni usar base64_encode, mi error fue pensar que como en C# al enviar en el header la codificación del usuario y password, también tenia que hacerlo en php, pero mas bien esta en una propiedad que viene en httpwebrequest de C#. En PHP CURLOPT_USERPWD ya lo hace.

Y aquí tengo las lineas de código que hacen la petición al webservice y me devuelven el resultado esperado.

```
//El webservice me pide los parámetros en formato de xml (no en un array como inicialmente lo estaba haciendo con $params), en este caso los parámetros son "siteId y sId" lo armo el xml y lo meto en una variable $xml.

$xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n";
$xml.= "<GServicesGM>";
$xml.= "<siteId>3</siteId>";
$xml.= "<sId>0</sId>";
$xml.= "</GServicesGM>";

//Esta parte es el Header de la petición por POST
try{
// La variable $ch contiene toda la información que nos requiere el webservice para darnos una respuesta, aqui primeramente la URL del webservice al abrir el curl_init.
$ch = curl_init('http://api.tuulbax.com/service.svc/getServicesGM');

// Aquí definimos que la petición es por POST.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

// Aquí enviamos la petición atraves del header, misma que nos pide el tipo de documento que pide el webservice, en este caso es un XML, y es importante poner el atributo Content-length, ya que de no ponerlo regresa un error, yo lo calculo con strlen. 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/xml','Content-length:'.strlen($xml)));

// Aquí ponemos los parámetros o datos que espera recibir el webservice en este caso es "siteId y sId" que los estamos enviando en un xml.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);

//Aquí indicamos que esperamos nos retorne el resultado
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//Aquí ponemos el usuario y password que nos pide el webservice para autentificarnos.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'myuser:mypass');

}catch(Exception $e){
    print_r($e);
}


$response = curl_exec($ch);

//Identifico el código que regresa el servidor, entre ellos puede estar el 500 de error, el 401 que es acceso denegado o el 200 que es de éxito.
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);


if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo "ERROR : ".curl_error($ch);
   }

curl_close($ch);

// Guardo la respuesta del webservice en un archivo físico XML
$new_xml = fopen ("./soap-response.xml", "w");
    fwrite($new_xml, $response);
    fclose($new_xml);
print_r($response);
```